# How much time it takes a Pegasus XL to reach launch altitude?

Tags: pegasus

On average, how much time it takes for the plane launching the Pegasus from the moment the plane starts to the moment it launches the rocket?

Comment: Each time could be different, it might be better to specify "typical", "average", "shortest possible" or "longest possible" or even "all of the above".

Comment: Is the moment of liftoff when the plane starts, or when the motor fires after being dropped from the plane?

Comment: Its obviously going to depend upon the location of the runway and the desired orbit inclination. Other than the min and max you could adjust the question to ask for a family of curves for inclination by starting place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It generally takes about an hour.

The IRIS launch take off and launch times are (infuriatingly) [documented](https://spaceflightnow.com/pegasus/iris/launchstory.html) in "local time" at 7:30 and 7:27 respectively (presumably with these events are in different timezones) at spaceflightnow.

Spaceflightnow also [mentions a 58 minute countdown](https://spaceflightnow.com/pegasus/aim/) for AIM .

NASA's timeline for the ST-5 mission has [takeoff activity at T-1 hour](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/st-5/launch/pegasus-101_prt.htm).

This ["live" recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltTar3RnQuQ) of the CYGNSS launch has the takeoff roll start at [T-57:45](https://youtu.be/ltTar3RnQuQ?t=710) with the [launch](https://youtu.be/ltTar3RnQuQ?t=4290) 60 YouTube minutes later.